# accessing a method in an array of objects that are in an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, object

How do I access an array of objects inside of an array of objects?

my code:

```
private boolean intersect(Polygon[] polygons, Line[] the_path, int i, int j)
{
   int k = 0;
   boolean intersect;

   if(intersect == true)
   {
       for(i = 0; i < polygons.length; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < polygons._lines.length; j++)
           for(k = 0; k < the_path.length; k++)
           intersect = polygons._lines[j].intersect(the_path[k]);
   } 

   return intersect;
}
```

The intersect method in the array of lines returns a boolean, but there is a separate array of line objects in each of the polygons....how do I go about accessing that method? (note..I don't know if this exact code will do what I want yet, but either way I need to be able to access that method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you accidentally left out the index into polygons (e.g. `polygons[i]`). Also, currently you have `intersect` being assigned the value of `intersect()` which means it is overwriting any other values given to the boolean `intersect` in previous loop iterations. I have added an `if` statement that will break out of the function immediately if that case if found instead. However, you could instead do something like `intersect = intersect || ... .intersect()` if you want to keep that variable.

Try this:

```
private boolean intersect(Polygon[] polygons, Line[] the_path, int i, int j) {
  int k = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < polygons.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < polygons[i]._lines.length; j++) {
      for (k = 0; k < the_path.length; k++) {
        if (polygons[i]._lines[j].intersect(the_path[k])) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked....how my only issue is figuring out where the null pointer exception is occurring and why  -_-

Comment: @user2489837 - No problem, happy to help :). Perhaps if you post your null pointer exception call stack we can help debug your issue.